# Live USB hanging

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, freeze, hang

Kali linux 2023 snapshot (usb persistent built ON USB DIRECTLY in qemu)

ASUS VIVOBOOK (16 GB RAM 19MB FRONT SIDE BUS)

Trying to setup a kali live usb to run fluxion (so i have to use kali more or less.)

Problem:

kali is booting extremely slow.  10-15minutes from persistence boot menu selection to full boot up

once booted up everything works quickly until a new window is opened or new program is started, then everything freezes for 5-10 minutes.  sync will not complete until whatever cycle is processing finishes.

after new window or program is started completely (5-10 minutes) then everything works quickly until one of the programs begins to process something or a new window/program is started; then system hangs again for 5-10 min.

this problem does not present in LIVE mode.  only presents in persistent live mode.  clean fresh install direct from recent snapshot.  occurs in both xfce and gnome environment.

any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What you report suggests you're using a drive with very low writing performance with or without additional factors it remains to be diagnosed.

Comment: ok thank you.  will check a different usb and update question accordingly.  thank you your comment reiterated a likely cause identified